# Right way to display an image using C++ with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

(i've updated the code the new better one)

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pkerkm/8251188947/in/photostream
good directions

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pkerkm/8252258464/in/photostream
bad directions

We are using SOIL library
C++
openGL

We drew the symbols of N, S, W, E on one of the images we are displaying, because     we thought that the images are being flipped or displayed incorrectly. We were right, but not sure why and how to fix it. Our W is up, E is down, S is right and N is left. This means, that the symbol N is on the left side, as to where it should be on the up part.

Here is the code where we generate the 3-dimmentional array and our pictures.

```
void genTex(){
texture[0]=SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL      texture 
    (
        "C:\\Users\\Pkerkm\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\files\\gameprojecgraphics\\bloodwall2.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
//glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
}

void /*GraphicsEngine::*/generateMap(){
  int i, k, j;
  double coordinates[8][3];
  for(i=0; i<MAPWIDTH; i++){
    for(j=0; j<MAPHEIGHT; j++){
      for(k=0; k<MAPDEPTH; k++){
    if(stage[i][j][k]==0){
      //do nothing
    }
    else if (stage[i][j][k]==1){
      getWallCoordinates(coordinates, i, j, k);
  if(j==0 || stage[i][j-1][k]==0){
        drawWall(coordinates[0],coordinates[1],coordinates[2],coordinates[3],true);
  }
      if(j<MAPHEIGHT-1 && stage[i][j+1][k]==0){drawWall(coordinates[7],coordinates[6],coordinates[5],coordinates[4],false);
  }
  if(i==0 || stage[i-1][j][k]==0){drawWall(coordinates[7],coordinates[4],coordinates[0],coordinates[3],false);
  }
  if(k==MAPDEPTH-1 || stage[i][j][k+1]==0){drawWall(coordinates[7],coordinates[3],coordinates[2],coordinates[6],false);
  }
  if(i==MAPWIDTH-1 || stage[i+1][j][k]==0){drawWall(coordinates[6],coordinates[2],coordinates[1],coordinates[5],false);
  }
  if(k==0 || stage[i][j][k-1]==0){drawWall(coordinates[5],coordinates[1],coordinates[0],coordinates[4],false);
 }
    }
   }
  }
 }
} 
void /*GraphicsEngine::*/drawWall(double a[3],double b[3], double c[3], double d[3], bool floor){
//glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);


if(floor){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
}else{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
}
//GLuint tex;
//glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
//glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

//glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

//glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

//tex = LoadTexture("wallsprite.png");
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3dv(a);
    glTexCoord2d(-1.0,0.0);
    //glVertex3dv(b);
    glVertex3dv(d);
    glTexCoord2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glVertex3dv(c);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,-1.0);
    //glVertex3iv(d);
    glVertex3dv(b);
glEnd();
/*glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);*/
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
 }
```

}

I am thinking the problem is in here, but not sure how to fix it

```
void /*GraphicsEngine::*/getWallCoordinates(double coordinates[8][3], double x, double y, double z){
int i;
for(i=0;i<8; i++){
    if((i/4)>=1){
        coordinates[i][1]=BLOCKHEIGHT*(y+1);
    }else{
        coordinates[i][1]=BLOCKHEIGHT*y;
    }
    if((i/2)%2==0){
        coordinates[i][2]=BLOCKDEPTH*z;
    }else{
        coordinates[i][2]=BLOCKDEPTH*(z+1);
    }
    if((i%4)%3==0){
        coordinates[i][0]=BLOCKWIDTH*x;
    }else{
        coordinates[i][0]=BLOCKWIDTH*(x+1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: opengl textures use the bottom left as (0,0), where as most other applications or normal images use the top left as (0,0), which would result in you image being displayed upside down if it was not read in the right way. Im not sure why your image is flipped around the x and y, but it may be something to do with how you are reading your image in

Comment: I have fixed something, but now i have one wall where N is left and W is down. also is there a way to post pictures here? or no.

Comment: Images are exactly like links, but they have an exclamation point in front of them: ![picture text](website link to picture)

Comment: okay, thanks not everything is facing the right way.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of a pencil and a blank piece of paper. Recreate exactly what you are doing here. You want to make a set of four points in counter clockwise order keeping in mind that UV coordinates go from 0.0 to 1.1 (lower left to upper right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply switch the glTexCoord2f instructions around to rotate the texture by 90 degrees.

Comment: Okay so now everything is facing the right way, the problem now is at coordinate Invisible wall is at 1,1,19 and 29,1,19. The third number increases and you go through the wall. So imagine a box, x,y, and z. The walls are drawn correctly but the z wall is drawn too early, where 1,1,19 and 29,1,19. there is a drawn wall there. the wall should be at 29,1,29 and 1,1,29. any comments?